# SCRIPT1028: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, webpack, safari, babel-loader

I am working on an React App, and I can not open this app in Safari and IE.

For `IE-11: SCRIPT1028: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number`

For `Safari(10.1.2) : SyntaxError: Unexpected token '...'. Expected a property name.`

my package.json file is as..

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.6.2",
    "@storybook/addon-backgrounds": "^3.4.8",
    "@storybook/react": "^4.0.0-alpha.4",
    "@types/d3": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/debug": "^0.0.30",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.1.9",
    "@types/jest": "^23.1.4",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.4",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.11",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.3",
    "@types/react-intl": "^2.3.16",
    "@types/react-mentions": "2.4.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.5",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/react-select": "^1.2.6",
    "@types/react-show-more": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/reactour": "^1.13.1",
    "@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
    "@types/redux-form": "^7.3.1",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/storybook__addon-backgrounds": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/storybook__react": "^3.0.8",
    "@types/styled-components": "^4.1.19",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-engine-plugin": "^0.3.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "connected-react-router": "^4.4.1",
    "cosed": "^1.1.8",
    "d3": "^5.7.0",
    "date-fns": "^1.29.0",
    "debug": "^3.1.0",
    "duplicate-package-checker-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "emoji-mart": "^2.6.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "gen-tester": "^3.1.2",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.0",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "immer": "^1.3.1",
    "jest": "^23.3.0",
    "jest-environment-enzyme": "^6.0.2",
    "jest-enzyme": "^6.0.2",
    "jest-styled-components": "^6.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^7.2.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
    "prettier": "^1.13.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-cosed": "^1.0.9",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-intl": "^2.8.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-select": "^1.2.1",
    "reactour": "^1.15.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-cosed": "^1.0.1",
    "redux-form": "^8.2.6",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.1",
    "ts-jest": "^23.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.13.0",
    "tslint-no-circular-imports": "^0.5.0",
    "typescript": "^3.0.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.7",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.15.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash.debounce": "^4.0.4",
    "firebase-tools": "^6.1.0",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8"
  }
```

If some more details needed please let me know.

Please suggest, what do i need to do.... Thanks

My `webpack.js` file is as....

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const {
  CheckerPlugin,
  TsConfigPathsPlugin,
} = require('awesome-typescript-loader');
const DuplicatePackageCheckerPlugin = require('duplicate-package-checker-webpack-plugin');

const ROOT = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.tsx?$/,
        use: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 25000,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /.html$/,
        use: 'html-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    modules: [path.resolve(ROOT, 'shared'), 'node_modules'],
    plugins: [new TsConfigPathsPlugin()],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: path.join(ROOT, 'shared', 'index.html'),
      filename: './index.html',
    }),
    new CheckerPlugin(),
    new DuplicatePackageCheckerPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

I think `babel-loader` will work but can't find any way to use babel-loader. I need this app to run on ie11 and safari as well.

Please suggest some solution...

Comment: Please try to refer [this article](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-polyfill) to install the react-app-polyfill package, and make the react application support IE browser. You could check the [Babel Loader document](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) to use it. Besides, here is a [similar thread](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9351), you could refer to it and try to add the "@babel/preset-flow" preset.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that by default the application was being rendered on IE7, that is - not on IE11/Edge that supports the transpiled build. So I had to mention the meta information to let the browser know that the intended browser is IE11/Edge. Add this to the head section of your index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Now you might be getting some errors in the console that read `SCRIPT5009: 'Set' is undefined` - refer to the below link relating to polyfills for the `Set` collection type:

[React JavaScript Environment Requirements](https://reactjs.org/docs/javascript-environment-requirements.html)

For more information on the issue see:

[React app not rendering in IE11 and below](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8379)

Answer (score -7):

Because you are opening it in Microsoft edge, try opening it in latest chrome version... problem will be solved.....this works for ReactJs projects

Comment: It's pretty common to use React apps on IE, Edge etc. This isn't really a constructive answer.